# How to center elements inside a gridLayout row?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I have a `gridlayout` with 3 `rows` and 3 `columns` (we make a tic tac toe game).

Inside these `rows` and `columns` should be `ImageViews`. However: My teacher centers them by changing the `margin` of every `ImageView` manually.
I think thats not the best way to do that, especially when having a larger amount of `rows` and `columns` as we do in this example.

Is there a better way to `center` all `ImageViews` inside the `rows`/`columns`?

The `xml` code is (with the first 3 images):

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="368dp"
    android:background="@drawable/board"
    app:columnCount="3"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:layout_column="0"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/coin_red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"  // This one we edit manually ...
        app:layout_column="1"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/coin_red" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        app:layout_column="2"
        app:layout_row="0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/coin_red" />
</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Is this your answer? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592065/how-to-layout-a-grid-of-images-in-the-center-of-the-screen)

Comment: not really, my images all have the same size so thats not a problem. I just want to use a Grid where every image is centered inside its own gridcell. That's easy to do in visual studio with xml, but I never found a solution (yet) on how to do this in android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got the effect you are looking for. It still takes quite a few lines, but the benefit with this is that it doesn't use hardcoded values.

You will want to set the column_weight and row_weight for each image view to 1 and set the layout_gravity to "center".

For example you would change your imageView1 to

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_rowWeight="1"
    app:layout_gravity="center"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/coin_red" />
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

According to me you can directly set your layout gravity to center

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/coin_red" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

Comment: Setting the "gravity" value alone didn't do the trick yet, but after adding everything from Nicolas' answer, it worked. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: sorry for wasting your time