# Should a custom View inside a custom ViewGroup use onDraw() or layout()?

Tags: android, android-view, android-custom-view, viewgroup

At first, I created a custom view that drew itself by overriding the `onDraw()` method. This turned out to be impractical because of the large amount of views I needed to create. So I've created a custom ViewGroup that draws each of it's childs with the `onLayout()` method.

I've read in the android documentation that the child view should implement a `layout()` method. But the child view I have made, uses the onDraw method to draw itself. How should I handle this? Should I get rid of the `onDraw()` method? And could anyone give me an example of how the `layout()` method works and how I should 'convert' my `onDraw()` method to a `layout()` method?

my current `onDraw()` method looks like this:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        //Draw Border.
        canvas.drawRect(mCellBounds, mBorderPaint);

        //Draw Background.
        canvas.drawRect(mBackgroundBounds, mBackGroundPaint);

        //Draw Value if not 0.
        if(Value != 0)
            canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(Value), ValueX, ValueY, mNumberPaint);

        //Draw Notes if Value == 0.
        else
        {
            for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
                if(NoteList[i])
                    canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i), NoteX + ((i%3) * NoteMeasureX), NoteY + ((i/3) * NoteMeasureY), mNotePaint);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I've created a custom ViewGroup that draws each of it's childs with
>   the onLayout() method.

I don't see how you draw the `ViewGroup`'s children in its `onLayout` method. That method should be used to position the children on the screen.

> I've read in the android documentation that the child view should
>   implement a layout() method

That method is already implemented, you call it with the right values so the `View` will know where it should be placed on the screen.

> Should I get rid of the onDraw() method?

If you want to actually see something you shouldn't ignore the `onDraw` method.

> And could anyone give me an example of how the layout() method works
>   and how I should 'convert' my onDraw() method to a layout() method?

You don't convert the `onDraw` method to the `layout` method. As an example, I made a small sample consisting of a custom `ViewGroup` along with a custom child `View`. The custom `ViewGroup` it will placed the two(expected children) like in the image below(each child will have half the width and height of the parent):

[image: custom ViewGroup]

You can find the sample [here](https://gist.github.com/4344689). I hope it helps you.
You could also have a look at the source code for the SDK layouts(like the simple `FrameLayout`) to see how they do their magic.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need the whole view hierarchy?
Consider using [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html), it's a much lighter way to do custom drawing and all on one view you can embed easily within other views.

See also my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268068/android-custom-layout/10709991#10709991).

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this. But for now, I would like to understand how a custom viewgroup works exactly so this question is important to me.